# How do I stretch a floated element to fill the vertical space in the viewport?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

Building a help system via Bootstrap. The left nav is supposed to fill the vertical space, regardless of the menu/content size.

Additionally, the footer needs to stick to the bottom when the page has little content, but should be pushed out of the way when the content increases (past the viewport height).

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lq33qnem/embedded/html,css,result/dark/#Html) setup.

The basic layout is:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <div id="system"></div>  <!-- This is the bar above the nav and content that shows the breadcrumbs -->
        <main id="content">
            <div class="row>
                <section></section> <!-- Contains the topic content -->
                <aside></aside>     <!-- Contains the left navigation. Floated left. 
                                    Needs to fill vertical space above/below it -->
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer></footer>           <!-- This needs to stick to bottom of page when /
                                    there is little content, and should be pushable /
                                    by longer (taller than the viewport) content -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

if has scroll add fixed to footer

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("body").height() > $(window).height()) {
        $('footer').css({
            'position':'fixed',
            'bottom':'0',
            'width':'100%'
        })

        $('body').css('padding-bottom','20px')
    } else {
        $('footer').css({
            'position':'static',
            'bottom':'auto',
            'width':'100%'
        })
        $('body').css('padding-bottom','0px')
    }
});
```